# error installing blitz++

Tags: blitz++

I need blitz++ to run a 3rd party library, but I'm not being able to compile it. The ./configure command runs well and sets the Makefile, but when i make it produces the following error:

```
    In file included from ../blitz/array/funcs.h:29:0,
                 from ../blitz/array/newet.h:29,
                 from ../blitz/array/et.h:27,
                 from ../blitz/array-impl.h:2515,
                 from ../blitz/array.h:32,
                 from ../src/globals.cpp:13:
../blitz/funcs.h: In static member function 'static blitz::Fn_abs<long int>::T_numtype blitz::Fn_abs<long int>::apply(blitz::Fn_abs<long int>::T_numtype1)':
../blitz/funcs.h:530:14: error: 'labs' is not a member of 'std'
../blitz/funcs.h:530:14: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:772:17: note:   'labs'
make[1]: *** [globals.lo] Error 1
```

I followed the instructions and I can't figure why is this happening. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and blitz 0.9. Also, I tried with both gcc 4.4 and 4.6. Please help a noob on a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blitz++ version 0.9 is seriously outdated. You will need to fetch the code in the source repository: 
hg clone http://blitz.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/blitz/blitz